# How I can use searching by Hibernate with Java

Tags: java, hibernate, search

I want to make searching on my database with hibernate in Java, how can I do that?

Normally when I am using JDBC I wrote this code :

`String Sql="select * from table1 where id like '"+jTextField1.getText()+"%'";`

but I want to do that with hibernate database operation,

do I need to use `session.load(..)` ?

Thanks from now...

And can ı display results in Jtable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Hibernate Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) Query

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyBean.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.like("name", "%xyz%"));
List results = crit.list();
```

Or a [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) query

```
session.createQuery("SELECT FROM MyBean WHERE name like '%xyz%'").list();
```

Comment: Thanks it's work and now can ı show that results in(jTable) by help f resultsettable model?
Or how can ı display result in swing based application?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use Hibernate Criteria queries.  Here's a [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) to a number of examples.

And, here's [another](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-Criteria-Queries-in-Depth/2/).

Essentially, you'll want to create a Criteria instance using the APIs, and then add Restrictions to that Criteria.